# Determine the number of digits of number in base 2 when you know the number in base 10

Tags: c++, numbers, radix

Someone asked me to determine how many digits does a number in base 2 has, when you know the number in base 10.

Is there any method to determine the number of digits of the number in base 2 without converting the number from base 10 to base 2?

At this moment I know only how to determine the number of digits of a number when converted to base 2, only if I compute the number in base 2.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking for *significant* digits?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I may be wrong, but since a binary number of *n* bits can represent a maximum decimal number of *2<sup>n</sup> - 1*, I would guess that a decimal number *k* would occupy at most *log<sub>2</sub>k + 1* bits.

Answer (score 2):

Just keep pulling bits out of the number, until you end up with zero.

```
int ndigits(unsigned n)
{
  int c=0;

  while (n)
  {
    ++c;
    n >>= 1;
  }

  return c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use logarithm for this kind of computation:

```
int number_of_base_2_digits(int x)
{
    return 1 + static_cast<int>(log2(x));
}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Jy0CGbbd9hCQGHVS)

This should be precise as long as you have enough precision in `double`.

You could extend this approach for any base

```
template<int Base>
int number_of_base_N_digits(int x)
{
    return 1 + static_cast<int>(log(x)/log(Base));
}
```

but it's much easier to run into precision problems due to how floating point arithmetics is implemented. I.e. the above works mostly okay on my machine, but returns 3 digits for 1000 in base 3.

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/IyCBpaBxJuSJg22E)

Answer (score 1):

Use [log<sub>2</sub>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/log2/) provided by `math.h`.

```
numOfDigits = floor(log2(decimal_value) + 1);
```

[Live demo.](http://ideone.com/CIehUg)

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) I'll try to answer accordingly.

An **unsigned** (not 2's complement) number *n* will occupy `std::floor(log2(k)) + 1` bits to be represented and that is also the number of *significant* digits needed to represent it.

It will occupy **all** of the available bits of the word or word-multiple you're using if that's negative.